# For loop returns ** value. Please explain

Tags: c++

Can someone explain please why the output of the following code is `**`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (float val = -10.0; val < 100; val = -val * 2)
    {
        if (val < 0 && -val >= 40)
            break;
        cout << "*";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would you please go bit by bit in the explanation? Thanks very much

Comment: Test it out on paper.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with and what have you done to figure this out?

Comment: the output is `**` because the for loop only reaches `cout` twice

Comment: @Pablo I think you are new to Stack Overflow, even I am, but its always nice to put your post in a good readable format. Because if not, it may happens that other won't be interested in reading your problem (as its difficult to) and you get off with no reply at all.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. You should say something about what output you expect and why you expect it. Then people could tell you why your expectation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Iteration 1

  - val is `-10`
  - `if ((-10 < 0) && (+10 >= 40))` is false

    - so it doesn't break out of the loop
  - `*` is printed
  - loop condition: `(-10 < 100)` is true

    - so the loop continues
  - val is then updated: `val = -val * 2`

    - `val = +10*2 = 20`
- Iteration 2

  - val is `20`
  - `if` statement short-circuits to false due to `(20 < 0)` being false

    - so it doesn't break out of the loop
  - `*` is printed
  - loop condition: `(20 < 100)` is true

    - so the loop continues
  - val is then updated

    - `val = -20*2 = -40`
- Iteration 3

  - val is `-40`
  - `if((-40 < 0) && (+40 >= 40))` is true

    - so it breaks out of the loop before printing again

Answer (score 0):

As your loop iterates thrice, but cout statement gets executed twice only, you get the output as **.

**Iteration 1: val = -10.0** (For loop condition is true and if block is false)

**Iteration 2: val = 20.0** (For loop condition is true and if block is false)

**Iteration 3: val = -40.0** (For loop condition is true but if block is true)

So, on third iteration as if condition becomes true, the loop exits.